# Android dialog doesn't click away anymore

Tags: android, dialog

I removed the black background of the dialog popup, but now it doesn't close after clicking around the dialog. Backbutton works fine, I'm guessing that an item is missing from the custom theme.

Here is the custom theme I am using.

```
<style name="customDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

NOTE: Even if i re-enable the black background by setting the `<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>` to true, it still doesn't click away. I'm pretty sure that I am missing a parameter.

Edit: Only change I made in the java code is:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.customDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Any java code for dialog box?

Comment: @D.B. added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just needed to add `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"` to the style.

EDIT: The missing parameter was `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>`